# jq select subset of nested keys

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I'm trying to build a SQL layer on top of jq for json files and I would like to implement the select. So far I got that:

```
 function join() {
     # If no arguments, do nothing.
     # This avoids confusing errors in some shells.
     if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
         return
     fi

     local joiner="$1"
     shift

     while [ $# -gt 1 ]; do
         printf "%s%s" "$1" "$joiner"
         shift
     done

     printf '%s\n' "$1"
 }

 function jselect {
     keys=`join "\":1, \"" $@`
     jq "with_entries(select(.key | in({\"$keys\":1})))"
 }
```

allows me to do

```
$ echo '{"success":true, "failure":false, "results":{"a": "...", "b": "...", "c": "..."}}' | jselect success results

>>> {
  "success": true,
  "results": {
    "a": "...",
    "b": "...",
    "c": "..."
  }
}
```

but I would like to be able to index nested properties as well something like:

```
$ echo '{"success":true, "failure":false, "results":{"a": "...", "b": "...", "c": "..."}}' | jselect success results

>>> {
  "success": true,
  "results": {
    "b": "..."
  }
}

or

>>> {
  "success": true,
  "results.b": "..."
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I didn't understand what you're asking, I think there is no need for extra shell script, you can use plain `jq` script:

```
echo '{"success":true, "failure":false, "results":{"a": "...", "b": "...", "c": "..."}}' | jq '{ success, results }'
```

The jq script only selects the 2 objects you want. Note the shorter form that uses 1 keyword per object (instead of `"success":.success`).

```
echo '{"success":true, "failure":false, "results":{"a": "...", "b": "...", "c": "..."}}' | jq '{ success, "results.b":.results.b }'
```

This script is almost the same except that the object name is explicit.